# The main differences between yii2 extension and library

Tags: yii2

I just started a yii2 project and I am trying to create a curl extension that I can reuse it in my future projects as well. When I opened "Extension Generator" on gii tool, I noticed that in the "Type" field we can provide:

- yii2-extension
- library

I would like to know the main differences between those two and some use cases that would feat the best for each type.

Comment: May be this page will help
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-gii-generators-extension-generator.html

If still confusion please raise a question on git hub

Comment: Unfortunately $type is missing description on that page at this moment. This is more likely a question regarding fundamental differences.

Comment: Looking at the hints() of that Generator class it uses the two words library and extension almost interchangeably. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/blob/master/generators/extension/Generator.php#L115 Form my tie workiung with composer 'library' is a framework agnostic group of code, thus IMO 'yii2-extension'  is a library specifically for Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

`library` default type of the composer package https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type

`yii2-extension` - Yii2 composer plugin https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/extensions/composer/README.md

Answer (score 0):

As I thought library stands for external stored packages into the composer.orgsite. which can be used by calling composer to extend Yii2 functionalities. if your created extension will be type of library than it must be kept over the package list of composer official site.
While yii2-extension is a type of extension file which are stored on the Yii official site.